# Rx-Android library import rx.android.plugins vs io.reactivex.android.plugins

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, rx-android

my `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0"
```

In using the exact libraries `External Libraries` shows `rxandroid-1.2.0` & `rxandroid-2.0.1` in one project of mine, whereas in another just shows the latter.

`1.2.0` uses `rx.android.schedulers.Scheduler;` which is compatible with `rx.Observable` when used as follows:

```
someRxObservable
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe();
```

`io.reactivex.Scheduler` used by `2.0.1` isn't, as it does not subclass `rx.Scheduler`. I'm not sure if this is a dependency gradle, in expecting to have downloaded both libraries by using gradle dependency mentioned above. That said however, in looking at the [source code on github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/2.x/rxandroid/src/main/java/io/reactivex/android/schedulers/AndroidSchedulers.java) for the latest version `2.0.1` it only shows the `io.reactive` solution.

Comment: Probably you have some other dependencies in your project. One of these may require 1.2.0 version of rxandroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io.reactivex` is the newer RxJava and the issue was that AndroidRx only works with version 2 of RxJava. The fix was to use `io.reactivex` across the board with its Observables, Schedulers, & Subscriptions.